# Bootstrap Tabbed Nav with Collapsing Categories

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have been trying to get a tabbed nav system working that allows the user to collapse tabs into category headings. Ideally the categories would automatically close if you select a tab outside of them, and would both look like a selected tab and actually select the first tab in their group when selected.

As of now, I have the nav functioning with the ability to show and hide certain tabs and all of the tabs work, but it is treating the tabs inside of the collapsible group as a different set from those outside it and, as such, does not deselect tabs properly. I was trying to remedy this using javascript, but I haven't figured out a way. Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Link to the code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8vap/1/).

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">
    <div class="side-nav-container affix-top">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a>
            </li>
            <div id="Tab1" class="collapse in">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" id="subnav">
                    <li class="active"><a id="subnavtab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Subtab1">Subtab1</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Subtab2">Subtab2</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Subtab3">Subtab3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span8">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Subtab1">Content 1a</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Subtab2">Content 1b</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Subtab3">Content 1c</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab2">Content 2</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab3">Content 3</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab4">Content 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any reason why you're using an outdated version of Bootstrap? I advise you at least upgrade to 2.3.2

Comment: Updating from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 doesn't change anything that I notice. Updating to 3.0.0 makes everything explode on the overall page, so I should probably figure that out. Either way, the issue that my question concerns is the same.

Comment: Yes I didn't really think it would fix the issue, I was just wondering if you were required to use version 2.2.1, and yes an update to version 3 requires some refactoring because of changes to some class names, it's definitely not a fast upgrade... anyways I think I got it working in v2, you can check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working but it required some slight changes in the markup plus some custom jQuery code.

Here's the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/67QVD/2/)**. Note that the CSS was also updated to accommodate for the markup changes.

Here's the resulting code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="side-nav-container affix-top">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a>
                    <ul class="subnav nav nav-tabs nav-stacked collapse in" id="Tab1">
                        <li class="active"><a class="subnavtab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Subtab1">Subtab1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="subnavtab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Subtab2">Subtab2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="subnavtab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Subtab3">Subtab3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab4">Tab4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Subtab1">Content 1a</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Subtab2">Content 1b</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Subtab3">Content 1c</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab2">Content 2</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab3">Content 3</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab4">Content 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.nav-tabs [data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function () {
    //Prevent the subnav from collapsing
    if ($($(this).attr('href')).hasClass('in')) return false;
    //Make collapse links act like tabs
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    //Activate first subtab
    $($(this).attr('href')).find('[data-toggle="tab"]').first().tab('show');
});

$('.nav-tabs > li > a').on('click', function () {
    //Hide any open subnav only if it's not the collapse link
    //also deactivate any active subtab
    if ($(this).data('toggle') != 'collapse') {
        $(this).closest('.nav-tabs').find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```